# MySQL relation and entities

Tags: android, mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables: `Place` and `Discount` with an N<->N relation. I also have another table called `place_discount` which has two foreign keys (`idPlace` and `idDiscount`).

When I add a discount to a place, e.g. discount for a bar, I add it in place_discount table.

So my issue is: I have an android app which queries on that database. when I want to list all the places that I have loaded, I want to show a star on those who have a discount.  To list that I do a `select * from place`. Is there a way to do that query?

Tip: I can not use triggers because I do not have super privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a join?

```
SELECT
  Place.*,
  IF(IFNULL(MIN(place_discount.idDiscount),0)>0,1,0) AS hasDiscount
FROM place
LEFT JOIN place_discount ON Place.id=place_discount.idPlace
GROUP BY Place.id
```

will give you a 1 in `hasDiscount` if a discount is available, a 0 if not.

On a side note: You do not need super privilege for a trigger on a table you own.

Comment: i have more than 100 places. when i did that query i received only the first record with the correct value for hasDiscount. Any idea?

Comment: I Fforgot the GROUP BY - added it now!

Comment: Works great this time!